# NodeJS Async : Not able to understand the flow

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mlab, node-async

```
async.each(
    driver,
    function(apiRequest, cb) {
        apicall(apiRequest, cb);
    },
    function(err) {
        console.log("error...");
    }
);

function apicall(item, cb) {
    request(
        'https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/db/collections/doc?q={"driverid": "' + item + '"}&apiKey=....',
        function(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log("----->" + body);
                var o = JSON.parse(body);

                for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
                    name[a] = o[i].first_name.concat(" ").concat(o[i].last_name);
                    modelname[a] = o[i].vehicleused.modelname;
                    modeltype[a] = o[i].vehicleused.modeltype;
                    ridescompleted[a] = o[i].ratings.ridescompleted;
                    avgrating[a] = o[i].ratings.avgrating;
                    ridescancelled[a] = o[i].ratings.ridescancelled;
                    behaviour[a] = o[i].ratings.behaviour;
                    timelypickupdrop[a] = o[i].ratings.timelypickupdrop;
                    conditionofvehicle[a] = o[i].ratings.conditionofvehicle;

                    console.log("DRIVER DETAILS---------------------------");

                    a++;
                }
            } else
                console.log("error....");
        }
    );
}
```

Now once I have gathered data in all the 9 arrays, I need to do processing on it. But that can be done only when all the 9 arrays have filled up with data about drivers.

But I am not sure from where to call the process_arrays function() which processes all the arrays only after the async.each has been finished.

Comment: You define a callback named `cb` for your `apicall()` function, but then you never actually call it.  So, `apicall()` never notifies anyone when it's done or has an error.  That can never work.  You have to call the callback when the async operation is done or has an error.

Comment: The modern way to do this would be to use the `request-promise` library instead of `request` and then use promises to monitor completion of your asynchronous operations, not the `async` library.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd argument (2nd function) to [`async.each()`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each) isn't just for errors. It's for specifying any continuation once the iteration has completed (or failed), such as calling `process_arrays()`.

```
async.each(
    driver,
    function(apiRequest, cb) {
        apicall(apiRequest, cb);
    },
    function(err) {
        if (err) console.log("error...", err);
        else process_arrays();
    }
);
```

Though, you'll also need to call the `cb` within your iterator function, `apicall(...)`, for both success and failure. Without doing that, `async.each()` won't continue to the next value in the collection.

```
function apicall(item, cb) {
    request(
        'https://...',
        function(error, response, body) {
            if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
                // argument means failure
                cb(error || new Error(response.statusCode));
            } else {
                console.log("----->" + body);
                var o = JSON.parse(body);

                // for loop ...

                // no argument means success
                cb();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Yup, it worked. Thank you for the detailed explanation